# Will gtk# support gtk 3.0?

Tags: gtk, gtk#, gtk3

GTK+ 3.0 released in February 2011. But unfortunately gtksharp doesn't support it yet. 
Are they going to support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, yes. One of the big improvements in GTK 3 was to make it much easier to automatically generate bindings to other languages.

In the meantime you might want to check out [Vala](https://live.gnome.org/Vala), a C#-like language that supports GTK 3.